# Why does .click() function differently in a jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm moving some javascript code to a jquery plugin.  The code clicks a tab on the page when you click some text.  Strangely the jquery plugin code behaves differently, it clicks the tab but it only partially loads(the code is in an extension and I don't have control over the code that loads the tab).  The jquery plugin calls a function that the page registers for and then clicks the tab... so it's like there's some security difference.

Does anyone have any ideas why?

```
//old code
        jQuery(document).on('click', '.mon-text', function () {

            if (jQuery('[data-mon]').length > 0) {
                jQuery('[data-mon]')[0].click();
            }

        });
```

New jquery plugin code

```
//new jquery plugin code
     plugin.$element.on('click', '.mon-text', function (e, result) {
            plugin.options.onMonClick();
      });
//this does not behave like the above code
   'onMonClick': function () {
         if (jQuery('[data-mon]').length > 0) {
            jQuery('[data-mon]')[0].click();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `plugin.$element`?  Is it `$(document)` ?

Comment: If it calls the `onMonClick` function, it can't behave different, because it calls the exact same functions inside jQuery. So please paste more code, there might be a difference somewhere.

Comment: @Taplar It's the plugin element, basically a div.  I'm using a plugin boiler plate design like this https://john-dugan.com/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-explained/